# Заголовок h1 не полностью покрасился в background-color

Tags: css

Почему то при задании стиля background-color не покрасил блок в красный цвет, восклицательный знак выходит из фона и живет своей жизнью.

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello,world!</h1>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вы ему задали ширину? Своей жизнью у вас живёт не восклицательный знак, а всё что дальше 250px

Comment: в учебном видео так было, и там кстати нормально отобразилось всё, это просто тренировка как работает миксин. Но появилась проблема странная, которую я хочу понять как решить   и почему она вообще появилась. Вот как в учебном видео выглядит https://sun9-61.userapi.com/impf/_wpWc-78rWPVCsWaJJ1Ms4711zwPRHt3dXsqaA/JtsrpxHMaME.jpg?size=481x317&quality=96&sign=ab27a9893493b9c8ead29c223436539b&type=album

Comment: В видео есть пробел по которому браузер смог перенести второе слово на другую строку. У вас же только запятая без пробела. Браузеры по умолчанию не рискуют разрывать строки без пробелов.

Comment: @Alexey Ten  блин, Вы гений, спасибо,почему Вы в комментарии ответили? Я бы Вам галочку в общем ответе зеленую поставил и у Вас рейтинг повысился

Comment: @AlexeyTen Можно было бы комментарии и ответом оформить.